# Можно ли в SQL добавить каретку?

Tags: sqlite, mysql, sql

Можно ли в SQL добавить каретку?

То есть есть строка, допустим, `"Первая строка, вторая строка.\nТретяя строка"`. Вот такого рода можно добавить в таблицу? Я просто посмотрел в откладчике, получается, что в  БД хрянится 2 символа `\=100` и `n=95`, а мне надо поставить символ `'\n'=10`. Как это сделать?

Comment: @xTIGRx, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
somestring + char(13) + char(10) + someotherstring
```

В MS SQL я делаю так, в MySQL вроде аналогичный синтаксис.